# Link to follow someone on WeChat / Weixin

Tags: android, mobile, wechat

I have a page with my company WeChat / Weixin QR Code. You cannot scan the QR code if you are viewing the site on your mobile *(quite a paradox for a mobile-based social network)*.
I would like to add a button that is only visible on touch enabled devices *(<--This part I know how to do)* that will automatically open WeChat / Weixin to the "Follow **user**" page.

I've found several sites that claim it is possible, but they are all in Chinese. I tried copying their code and just changing the unique WeChat / Weixin user ID code, but it does nothing.

Also, the official WeChat dev page gives no info on how to do this.

Optimally, this should work on any mobile OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
   weixin://
```

is a WeChat PRIVATE/PROPIETARY Protocol handler, it will ONLY work on WeChat apps

for instance if you enter the following link on a WeChat browser app, the app will know what to do:

```
   weixin://contacts/profile/icewent
```

and send you to the WeChat Profile of this "icewent" user

if you scan a QR Code with the WeChat app, it will know what to do, because all the QR code do is encode the:

```
   weixin://contacts/profile/icewent
```

PRIVATE `weixin://` PROTOCOL link into a QR Code...

using the PRIVATE `weixin://` PROTOCOL in a regular browser will NOT work!

regular browsers implements PUBLIC PROTOCOLS like:

```
   http://
   https://
   ftp://
```

regular browsers do NOT implement PRIVATE/PROPIETARY PROTOCOLS like:

```
   weixin://
```

Answer (score -2):

PLEASE NOTE THIS FUNCTIONALITY HAS BEEN DEPRICATED

Wechat Protocol is weixin://

We are currently aware of 2 different ways to call this:

weixin://contacts/profile/USERNAME - USERNAME is a variable that you will replace.

So you will call this like John Doe